# Why do Java regular expressions behave differently on Linux and Windows?

Tags: java, regex, linux, windows

This is a general question. I'd like to know do they behave differently and why, or do they behave differently only when we do something wrong ?

This is what I'm currently struggling with.
I have this regex:

```
CLASS_NAME_VALIDATION_REGEX = "([a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z\\d_$]*\\.)*[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z\\d_$]*";
```

and I use it like this:

```
Pattern.matches(CLASS_NAME_VALIDATION_REGEX, qualifiedClassName)
```

So under Unix/Linux `matches()` returns true for `java.io.Serializable` on Windows it returs false.

Have I escaped something improperly or is there something else I'm not aware of ?

Thanks,

---

So its probably not the regex that is the problem and I'm thinking of closing this question since it would be very much off topic if I'm right.

I'm currently reading a file containing class names and matching each name with the regex. Each name is on a separate line.

Could it be a case of different characters for carriage return on Windows and Linux ?

Comment: To make it easier for us to play with this, please include an SSCCE (you _almost_ have it already).

Comment: @NPE SSCCE ? (min chars)

Comment: Sorry, should have included a link: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Basically, something we can copy-and-paste, and run without modifications.

Comment: It returns `true` for me on Windows...

Comment: @JonSkeet yes I just tried it ... It could be another problem, I'll give you the whole class in a moment.

Comment: My guess: make sure there aren't any extra characters in `qualifiedClassName`.  Perhaps on Windows, it started out as something with an `\r\n` in it, and you removed the `\n` but there's still an `\r` stuck in it?  P.S. I added this at the same time you were editing your question.  Spooky.  Happy Halloween.

Comment: @ajb :D spooky indeed, I'm wandering what to do about the question though and you're probably right, I'll update it again once I find the problem since some of you are probably curious, but I'll probably close it since it seems misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTest
{
    private static final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z\\d_$]*\\.)*[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z\\d_$]*");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String data = "java.io.Serializable";
        Matcher m = pat.matcher(data);
        System.out.println(m.matches());
    }

}
```

Output:

```
true
```

Answer (score 4):

So it turns out the problem is not the regex as commenters pointed out.

For anyone finding this question **java regexes do not work differently on Windows and Linux**.

The actual problem was that on Linux lines end with `\n` while on Windows they end with `\r\n` and as ajb suggested I had a leftover `\r` at the end of each class name.

So

`Pattern.matches("([a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z\\d_$]*\\.)*[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z\\d_$]*", "java.io.Serializable\r")`

returned `false`.